# Measure of product sets equal to product of measure of sets?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m,V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ are measurable sets. I am thinking about how we could prove $|U\times V|=|U||V|$ without using Fubini's Theorem. Probably we need to prove it by definition. If $U,V$ are boxes, it is simple. Next in general, we come to the case that $U,V$ are open. I could prove $|U\times V|\le|U||V|$, but I don't know how to prove the other direction.

Comment: You could use the monotone class theorem or Dynkin's $\pi - \lambda$ lemma.

Comment: It depends on how you define the product measure.